# Scale SVG (Raphaël) paths from center on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael, scale

I'm trying to scale SVG paths on mouse hover but because I had to transform the paths as I add them to the paper it has made a mess of the result.

Please see:
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/Kc4q2/

The paths are added with this transform attribute:

`transform: 'S2.5,2.5,0,0'`

and on `mouse in` I animate with:
`this.animate({transform: 's2.9,2.9,0,0'}, 200);`

and `mouse out` I restore with:
`this.animate({transform: 's2.5,2.5,0,0' }, 400, "bounce");`

After checking around here I found people mentioned `element.getBBox()` and I tried this but I'm screwing up.

```
var center = this.getBBox();
var adjustx = center.width / 2 ;//+ center.x;
var adjusty = center.height / 2 ;//+ center.y;
adjustx = (1 - 3)*adjustx;
adjusty = (1 - 3)*adjusty;
```

Could anyone point out what I'm missing please?

Or recommend a good tool to resize the SVG paths to a new default. I've tried inkscape and http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html

tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with transformations is my least favorite part of Raphael. It's possible I'm missing an obvious solution here, but here is how I fixed it:

- get the bounding box before the original transformation, when the shape is drawn exactly as the path specifies.
- Calculate the dx and dy difference between the center of the shape before and after the mouseover. if bbox is the original, pre-scaling bounding box, then for dx this would be 2.5 * (bbox.x + bbox.width / 2) - 2.9 (bbox.x + bbox.width / 2). This can obviously be reduced.
- translate the magnified shape backward by these amounts.

In code:

```
    var obj = paper.path(paths[county].path);
    obj.bbox = obj.getBBox();
    obj.attr({ transform: 'S2.5,2.5,0,0' });

    obj.mouseover(function (e) {
        var dx = -0.4 * (this.bbox.x + this.bbox.width / 2);
        var dy = -0.4 * (this.bbox.y + this.bbox.height / 2);
        this.animate({ transform: 'S2.9,2.9,0,0T' + dx + ',' + dy}, 200);
    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        this.animate({ transform: 's2.5,2.5,0,0' }, 400, "bounce");
    });
```

Here's an [updated fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/Kc4q2/8/). For reference, I have it drawing red and blue rectangles representing the pre- and post-mouseover bounding boxes -- a strategy I use whenever transformations are giving me dyspepsia. You'll want to remove them, naturally.

One other thing to remember: The actual center of an irregular shape is its [center of mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass), not the halfway point of its bounding box. (These two points are only the same if it's a perfectly symmetrical shape, which geographic boundaries rarely create.) For shapes like the state of Alaska, with lots of islands way off in the corner, this can make a center-based scaling look awkward.

If you wanted to get really fancy, you could try and calculate the center of mass for each shape. But I doubt you want to go there, and offhand these counties appear to have roughly even distribution of mass around the center.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, I learned a lot from what you did. I immediately tried to replicate your solution in my main project page and got a strange result. The first hover on a path works perfectly but all subsequent hovers cause the path to move in ever increasing distances away from its original position. After a lot of trial and error I found that if I removed everything to do with your reference boxes it caused the problem.
 http://jsfiddle.net/Kc4q2/15/  but if you uncomment //var box = this.getBBox(); it works. Have you seen this before? Thanks again.

Comment: That was sloppy on my part. Since "this.bbox" was a reference to the object's bounding box, which changes with each scale, the adjustx and adjusty values were changing each time. But there's no reason I see for calculating them more than once. See updated fiddle: dx and dy are now properties of the object computed once when it is created. http://jsfiddle.net/Kc4q2/16/

Comment: I came across something similar before demonstrated in the link below. I found that if you make a binding inside a function and then you call that function on an event you end up with 2^x, x=iterations. When I saw the paths moving at increasing  distances it reminded of the below example. You really have saved me a LOT of work. Thank you, I'll post the final here when college allows me to finish it. http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/acNwn/